# How to get only list of dependencies that are installed from Dockerfile in a container and not preinstalled?

Tags: docker

I have a docker image downloaded from docker hub and that contains pre-installed dependencies which I don't want. I want to find out all the dependencies + transitive dependencies that are installed from my "Dockerfile" on top of the docker hub base-image. I tried looking for an open source program to do this but I could not find anything that seems suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build your own or simply if they share their source you can modified from them.

Sample of mysql docker source :
https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/tree/master/8.0

You can clone their repo and then modified the Dockerfile to your requirement.
But if their base image contain pre-installed that you dont want then you have to build your own.